# Change Listen Port on httpd config for Varnish Configuration

Tags: apache, centos, varnish, varnish-vcl

I installed Varnish Cache my CentOS server.I try the do configuration correctly but as I read many document say to me change apache port `Listen 80` to `Listen 8080`. But I couldn't find any Listen 80 line on my server `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` but i found `0.0.0.0:80` line. Is it same thing ? If those are same thinhgs, when i change my sites not working.

I know that I make huge logical mistake but i can't understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

In this file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` there should be a line: ServerRoot `"/etc/httpd"`
Below this line there is `Listen 80` Change this to `Listen 8080` and restart apache

Restarting with command: /etc/init.d/httpd restart

I also found this:-> http://updatedlinux.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/how-to-change-the-default-port-number-for-apache-http-server/

Possible that this will help!

Comment: I am sorry. I search `ServerRoot` and `/etc/httpd` string in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`but there is no both.

Comment: Could you please provide apache version: [link]http://pixert.com/blog/how-to-find-apache-version-on-linux/
And also centos version. 

This is quite crazy because with me it is!

Comment: `Server version: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)
Server built:   May 10 2013 00:34:01
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.18.13 rev9999` cenos version : `CentOS release 5.8 (Final)`

Comment: I believe it should be in `/var/cpanel/cpanel.config`

Look this link: [link]http://serverfault.com/questions/289067/make-apache-on-cpanel-listen-to-8080

Comment: I can do this with Tweak settings on WHM and I understand that `Listen 80` same with `*:80` . But when i change 80 to 8080 i get `could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8080` error.

Comment: Meaning there is already something bind to 8080:
[link]http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-server-ports.html

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like SELinux is standing in the way and is prohibiting the use of your custom port.

So the solution should be one of these:

- a) disable SELinux (if your scenario allows it and you don't need it)
- b) set SELinux permissive
- c) configure SELinux to allow your custom port for the httpd service

see */etc/sysconfig/selinux* for a) and b)

use *semanage* for c)

HTH

Comment: Correct. Use `8008` instead of `8080`